# How to maintain total column in database

Tags: laravel

I'm new to laravel. I have one income table in the database and I want to maintain the total amount of users but there is a condition if the same user adds new deal_price then all the column will be updated except total and total will be updated like old deal_price+new deal_price.

this my controller

```
 public  function storeincome(Request $request){


    $date=$request->get('date');
    $parse_date=Carbon::parse($date)->format(' d-m-y H:i');
    $party_name = $request->Input('party_name');
    $deal_price = $request->Input('deal_price');
    $mode = $request->Input('mode');
    $slug = Str::slug($party_name, '');
    $total = $request->Input('deal_price');
    $data = array('date'=>$parse_date,'party_name'=>$party_name,'deal_price'=>$deal_price,'mode'=>$mode,'party_slug'=>$slug,'total'=>$total);
    Income::insert($data);
    return redirect(route('admin.dashboard'))->with('success', trans('message.success.create'));
}
```

[this my table colums](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQvwi.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just update other columns normally and while updating the column 'total', fetch the value of deal_price(old) from your database and store it in a variable ($old_deal_price).

Now, just add the old_deal_price ($old_deal_price) and new_deal_price ($request->deal_price) and update that value in your 'total' field.

```
$total = ($old_deal_price) + ($request->deal_price);
```

Goodluck!